# Korean for "commit" as in code

Tags: translation

I'm working on a project that uses version control. I'm having trouble translating "commit" as in `git commit`.

A sample sentence would be "After you've fixed the bug you'll need to commit your code."

I've arrived at 코드를 커밋하 but I'm not sure that's quite right.

Thank you!

Comment: For the example sentence I'd say, "버그 고친 담에 커밋하셔야 해여"

Comment: I think 커밋 would be the closest translation, so 커밋하다. It also seems to be used online. Eg: https://item4.github.io/2016-11-01/How-to-Write-a-Git-Commit-Message/

Answer (score 3):

Koreans say

- “커밋” (Transliteration “커밋”) for the noun “commit” (as in `git commit`),
- “커밋하다” (Transliteration “커밋” ＋ Verbing suffix “-하다”) for the verb “to commit,”

since there's no *good* translations for those.

---

And for the verb ― don't forget to **conjugate** it.

> “After you've fixed the bug you'll need to commit your code.”
>
> “그 버그 고친 다음에 (그) 코드 커밋**해야** 합니다.”

Answer (score 1):

If you intend 'fix the bug' as a condition, you should say like below.

> After you've fixed the bug
>   버그를 고친 후에는
>
> you'll need to commit your code.
>   해당 코드를 커밋해야 합니다.

-> 버그를 고친 후에는 해당 코드를 **커밋**해야 합니다.

Answer (score 0):

Because commit is noun, You can make noun **"커밋"** into verb if you put **"-하다"**(Verbing suffix) after noun.

For example, translation for "Please commit!" would be **"커밋해 주세요!"**

> After you've fixed the bug -> (너가) 그 버그를 고친 뒤에는 ("you" can be ommited)
>   you'll need to commit your code. -> (너의) 코드를 커밋해야 합니다. ("you" can be ommited)

Answer (score 0):

commit : commit one's ideas to writing 자기의 착상을 적어두다

In computer, if we have an important change and we write it, then we
know the history. That is, "commit" may be 변경사항기록
(change-writing). But it seems that Koreans use 커밋.